# How to get root level domain to go to www

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, dns, subdomain, amazon-route53

I am using Amazon Web Services. I have an Elastic Load Balancer setup so my http://www.somesite.com goes to the load balancer.

What I want to do is to have http://somesite.com to go there too.

What is the best way to set this up?

All my stack is setup using Amazon Route 53. I got my domain using Amazon, and I have a hosted zone there.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.  I have listed some examples below.

1. http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/10/04/web-page-redirects-on-amazon-s3-hosted-websites/ along with http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html
2. http://wwwizer.com/naked-domain-redirect
3. http://webdesign.about.com/od/http/a/aa021207.htm

Comment: Solution 1 seems to work. Just to clarify, I went to Route53 > Hosted Zones > Create Record Set. The fields were -- name: blank, Type: A (IPv4 address), Alias: Yes, Alias Target: my elb, Routing Policy: Simple. It seems to work fine. Is this correct?